# Modify axis to display zero-values as a small bar too

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to display a small bar for zero values too. I achieved that by decreasing the y axis first range parameter:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height-10, 0]);
```

The resulting bars look like i want them to look, but the y axis has a gap, that i like to close (below the zero):

[image]

Any hints on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Add a small value to 0?

Comment: I want that 0- tick to be some pixels above the abscissa. Which leads to the zero-bars to automatically show up. I did not point that out in my question, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve the issue by drawing the small line by hand:

```
var line = d3.svg.line().x(0).y(function(d) {return d;});

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(yAxis)
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', line([height, height - 10]));
```

Still i was hoping to resolve this by some configuration in D3 itself.